# What is a "regulation pistol"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is a "regulation pistol"? It's puzzling to see a man buying a gun before going to the front. I thought soldiers are provided with guns for free. From Hemingway's Farewell to Arms

> The pistol felt heavy on the belt. Still, I thought, it was better to have a **regulation pistol**. You could always get shells.

Comment: Remember that the character is an American volunteering to serve in the Italian ambulance corps—not a soldier. A weapon was probably not issued to such men.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pistols for use by soldiers.

Whether the firearms are bought by the army and given to soldiers, or (as was often the case) soldiers were expected to provide their own weapons, there was a need for the weapons to be interoperable.  That would mean that if you ran out of ammunition, you could get some from the other men in your platoon, or from stores etc.

And so there were regulations on what pistols a soldier could have. A pistol that met these regulations would be a "regulation pistol" and so suitable for use in the army.

This is why "you could always get shells"  Shells are bullets, and if you had a regulation pistol, finding the proper size bullets would not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this case "regulation" is referring to Army regulations, so a "regulation pistol" is one mandated by those regulations. As the passage states it's always possible to get ammunition for such a pistol. Something you provide yourself might not be so easy.